# Cannot Traceroute/ssh outside network

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04, networking

My server cannot connect to ANYTHING EXTERNAL via ssh.  I also cannot traceroute to any of them.  Machines on the same network work fine via SSH and traceroute.  This machine is connected to the internet as I can fetch and install packages just fine.  I can also SSH to this machine.  It's just outgoing SSH/traceroute that isn't working for some reason.

SSH:

```
Connection refused
administrator@nrj-linux-staging:~$ ssh administrator@testing2.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
```

Traceroute:

```
traceroute to testing2.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  * * *
2  * * *
3  * * *
4  * * *
5  * * *
6  * * *
7  * * *
8  * * *
9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * *

traceroute to www.google.com (74.125.227.50), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  * * *
2  * * *
3  * * *
4  * * *
5  * * *
6  * * *
7  * * *
8  * * *
9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
```

Netstat:

```
administrator@nrj-linux-staging:~$ netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:6379          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.42:http-alt      *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:ftp                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:5984                  *:*                     LISTEN     



tcp6       0      0 [::]:47439              [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:tproxy             [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:51774              [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp6       0      0 [::]:33848              [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*                             
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6938     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     7517     /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7527     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7850     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10483    /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7889     /home/gitlab/gitlab//tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket
```

Routing Table:

```
administrator@nrj-linux-staging:~$ route -n   
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.225      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I can ping the gateway:

```
administrator@nrj-linux-staging:~$ ping 10.0.0.225
PING 10.0.0.225 (10.0.0.225) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.225: icmp_req=1 ttl=255 time=0.354 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.225: icmp_req=2 ttl=255 time=0.310 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.225: icmp_req=3 ttl=255 time=0.314 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.225: icmp_req=4 ttl=255 time=0.325 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.225: icmp_req=5 ttl=255 time=0.431 ms
```

This box has an identical interface configuration.  It is also worth noting that other boxes on this same network apparently have an identical problem.

The DNS is pointed to the gateway.

The firewall on this network is set up to allow secure shell outgoing, ip outgoing, etc.  I am not sure what else is required to get this working.  I can provide you with whatever else you guys need.  I am using a cisco firewall with the ADSM utility via a windows box.  Thanks for the help

Here is how NAT is configured RIGHT NOW:

We have two sites, we will call them site a and site b.

Site b is in the building that our developers work.  Site A is production, and contains the firewall.  The root domain name of our product points to the static global IP of Server 'A'.  On the firewall, when traffic on the ssh service is detected as incoming to the address of Server 'A', it translates it to keep the original source and set the destination to server  'B' which is the linux box that I need to be able to secure shell out of back to site 'B'.  There is also a NAT rule that translates outgoing packets with a source of server 'b' to have a source of server 'a' and keep the original destination.

Thanks again for the help

Comment: Can you post your local routing table?

Comment: Can you ping the default gateway by IP (10.0.0.225)? Where are you getting name resolution from (or trying to?)

Comment: Yes:  `ping 10.0.0.225
PING 10.0.0.225 (10.0.0.225) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.225: icmp_req=1 ttl=255 time=0.354 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.225: icmp_req=2 ttl=255 time=0.310 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.225: icmp_req=3 ttl=255 time=0.314 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.225: icmp_req=4 ttl=255 time=0.325 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.225: icmp_req=5 ttl=255 time=0.431 ms`

Comment: Can you ping anything outside from the 10.0.0.225 box? So far, this looks like a case of that box (I'm guessing it's the firewall) not packet-forwarding correctly.

Comment: It appears that I cannot ping from other boxes on this network either, nor can I ssh.  Everything gives access denied via SSH and ping/traceroute returns nothing but a timeout

Comment: That definitely looks like a problem on the firewall.

Comment: Any advice there?  I was suspicious that it was the firewall due to the fact that the returned "connection refused" is instantanious

Comment: If you have control of the firewall, check packet forwarding settings. If you don't have control of it, tell who does to "fix it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the subnet can't go out, it is probably a firewall issue. Since you're using ASDM, you have an ASA firewall. Check the access list on the interface with 10.0.0.225 (assuming that is your ASA) and make sure you have ICMP and SSH allowed. Remember: ASA rules are automatically reflexive, meaning that any rule only needs to be set in the direction it is started (in your case from 10.0.0.0/24 to any, protocol ssh and ICMP). If you want to check whether or not the ASA should forward the packet, you can use `packet tracer` under tools in your ASDM. Two tips:

1. Make sure to select the correct starting interface (I always forget)
2. Make sure to uncheck `Show Animation`, since all it does is show an animation and make you wait longer.

Comment: I added a rule to the inside interface where source is any and destination is any allowed.  It still won't traceroute OR ssh

Comment: What is the IP of the inside interface on the ASA. Is it 10.0.0.225? What does packet tracer say?

Comment: The IP address of the ASA is 225

Comment: Is the network you are trying to ping inside your own network, or are you trying to ping the internet? If so, are you using NAT? Could you post the ACL's on this interface and any config pertaining to NAT? You can easily get the asa config by going to https://10.0.0.225/exec/show%20run